# Cypress: Stubbing a particular key in JSON response

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to stub the following response in Cypress. Specifically stubbing the key `ds_version`, which could have a possible value of 0, 1, or 2. Each value would display a different element on the UI.

```
fixtures/user.json

{
"email": "test@test.com",
"firstName": "Test",
"lastName": "Test",
"ds_version": 0, --> switch this value to 0, 1, 2 for different test scenarios
"country": "Indonesia",
...
}
```

I was able to achieve this by providing the whole JSON as `cy.route()` parameter, like below:

```
cy.server();
cy.route('GET', '/users/current', 'fixture:user.json').as('getUsersCurrent');
```

It seems that if I want to test for `ds_version=1` or `ds_version=2`, I would need to provide different JSON with changed value. Is there a way to provide a different `ds_version` value while the rest of JSON remain the same?

Comment: You can use the `cy.route2()` from cypress. To enable it write in your cypress.json `"experimentalNetworkStubbing": true`. In your test file `cy.route2('GET', '/users/current', 'fixture:user.json', (req) => { req.reply((res) => { let list = JSON.parse(res.body);list.ds_version = 1;res.send(list);})})`. Give this a try.

Comment: Thank you @AlapanDas. Quite brilliant function and actually I did not need to use `fixture` (so I don't need to prepare any JSON beforehand). ``` cy.route2('GET', '/users/current', (req) => {
            req.reply((res) => { 
                let responseBody = JSON.parse(res.body);
                responseBody.ds_version = 2;
                res.send(responseBody);
            })
        }).as('getUsersCurrent');```

Comment: So did it fix your problem ?. If yes I will post this as a answer so that it might help others as well.

Comment: Yes, it did solve my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [cy.route2()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route2.html) from cypress:

1. Go to `cypress.json` and write `"experimentalNetworkStubbing": true`
2. In your *test.spec* file write:

   ```
   cy.route2('GET', '/users/current', (req) => {
       req.reply((res) => {
           let list = JSON.parse(res.body)
           list.ds_version = 1
           res.send(list)
       })
   })
   ```